# force to run unicode (input and output) cmd.exe

Tags: windows-7, unicode, registry, cmd

I need , when I execute a bach file (*.bat) ,the file run with cmd /u (command prompt with Output UNICODE Characters).

maybe change registery win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it from another batch, calling cmd /U /C second.bat